# VB.Net Opening Excel Throws "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)'"

Tags: excel, vb.net, windows-7, excel-interop

I got a new computer (Dell Latitude with 64 bit Windows 7 Enterprise with Service Pack 1) at work and ever since I have had issues with the following  code:

```
Dim eApp as New Excel.Application
Dim eBooks as Excel.Workbooks
Dim eBook as Excel.Workbook
eBooks = eApp.Workbooks
eBook = eBooks.Open(fileName)
```

When I was using Excel 2010, the last line was throwing: The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

After upgrading to Excel 2016, the line is now throwing: Exception from HRESULT: 0xE06D7363

These errors are only being thrown on my machine. I have had coworkers with with both excel 2016 and 2010 test out a build made on my new computer with no issues. One of them even had the same model laptop as I do, and she received it the same day.

I checked what versions of .Net we were using, and one of them had the exact same version as me.

The exception is being throw for both .xlsm and .xlsx files.
It is being thrown for both files on my computer and on the network.
It is being thrown when run in Visual Studio 17 Professional and when run from the release build.
The DCOM config security setting for Excel are the same on my old computer as they are on my new computer.
I am able to open Excel files on my computer.
I am the only person in my company with a Visual Studio license

I am at my whits end and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT: The app is a windows form. There is no try/catch block surrounding this code or the line that calls the function containing the code.
After IT deleted VS, used a free registry cleaner on my computer, and made me reinstall VS, I now am back to seeing HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a few things? Such as whether your app is a windows form or web MVC? HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT) Is usually not the first error it should encounter. Is your piece of code up there wrapped in a try/catch ?

Comment: @AmaoMao I have added an edit to address your questions.

Comment: Mind if we see a more complete version of your code, as is how the piece of codes reside in your whole structure?

Comment: Or you might want to refer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1124945/excel-interop-remote-procedure-call-failed-or-rpc-e-serverfault)

Comment: @AmaoMao Thank you! Your link solved the issue. It was Foxit. Because this has already been answered in the superuser forum, should even I  post an answer to my question?